# Simplest way of eliminating objects from queryset in Django

Tags: python, django

I have a query set,  `categories = unipart.categories.all()`, which is all the categories that a unipart object is linked to.

However, I'd like to remove the top-level categories from this list -- ie. those with subcategories that the unipart is also listed within.

Or those categories with a parent_id equal to one of the category_ids in the queryset.

For example if a unipart was listed in:
Nutmeg (parent= Spices) and
Spices (parent = Food)

then I'd want to ONLY include Nutmeg -- so basically I want to 'pop' Spices from the queryset.

What is the best way to do this? I would rather not use a list.

Here's my models:

```
class UniPart (models.Model):
categories=models.ManyToManyField(Category, related_name = 'unipart')

class Category (MPTTModel):
    category = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    oc_id= models.IntegerField()
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True, related_name='children')
    def __unicode__(self):
```

Comment: Posting your models always helps rather then describing the relationships in words.

Comment: What's categories Manager? Could you show the code of it please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your can exclude those categories who has a child category binded to this unipart item:

```
categories = unipart.categories.exclude(
                 categorieschild__unipart = unipart).distinct()
```

Here `categorieschild` is de related name for the categories children.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not sure this is working though. I posted my models above. I'm still getting the parent categories of children.